# Examples of using web calls to StatSoft Statistica Enterprise Server 12

Tags: .net, xml, web-services

Anybody know how to access to Statistica Enterprise Server API using web calls?

On StatSoft website is nothing about it.

Comment: Have you allready tryed googeling it? Please give us as much information about your problem as possible! Thanks

Comment: Of course I googled it. Nothing regarding web service calls. Only COM calls (one small example) on statsoft website.

Comment: They have documentation for COM call but it looks like just classes descriptions. There is nothing information about arguments for methods, for example, argument "ScriptURI" for method "SubmitJob". What I have is only argument name, no description, no examples how to use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To the best of my knowledge, there is no publicly available documentation on Enterprise Server's web service calls (except, perhaps, for Live Score).
You should try contacting their tech support and explain what you're trying to achieve (or email developerdocumentation@statsoft.com). I'm pretty sure that they will help you out, but they'll most likely point you to [the API](http://sdn.statsoft.com/STATISTICAVisualBasic.aspx?page=category&item=server) instead of using web service calls directly.

I have plenty of experience with the STATISTICA API so I may be able to help you further if you can provide more information.